# Use lightning-lookup-address in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to use LWC component lightning-lookup-address in Salesforce.

It works fine in webcomponents.dev, but I cannot save it in Salesforce:

"NO MODULE named lightning:lookupAddress"

```
<template>
    <lightning-lookup-address></lightning-lookup-address>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the snippets of code relevant to your LWC use of this component. Make sure to include relevant import statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use [officially documented components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/) in Salesforce LWC. This lookup component exists in [lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components) package, which does not contain all the components available in Salesforce LWC, and does include some components not available in Salesforce LWC. You can use this component in a LWC OSS environment (including webcomponents.dev), but you won't be able to use it directly in Salesforce LWC until/unless it is officially released. You can use [lightning-input-address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address/example) instead.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation